# HP PCIe 8GB FC Adapter not visible on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: hp-proliant, fibre-channel, pci-express

Anyone who can assist me.

I have a HP Proliant GL360, On Boot, the HP PCIe 8GB FC Adapter drivers are visible. Once logged on the server, when I go to Network Connections, I can't see the adapters.

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I go to Network Connections, I can't see the adapters

Hahaha, are you trolling us? it's not a network adapter!

Seriously, it's an FC HBA, you need to install the HBA drivers and MPIO, connect it to an FC switch, zone the HBA into a VSAN that's linked to an FC array of some form that's also presenting LUNs to the pWWN of that HBA and then once that's done you can refresh your storage, see the disk/s presented and finally partition, format and mount them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still new on this, forgive me for asking something u find it funny. I am trying to configure DAS between the Proliant and MSA 2040. I am not winning in connecting the two

Comment: DAS as in SAS? Which exact model of 2040 have you got - there's at least three models.

Comment: Direct Attach Storage, HP MSA 2040 Dual Controller

Comment: So the HPE P/N: C8S53A then? In which case you need a compatible SAS HBA, not an FC one - happy to find you a compatible parts list but I need to know the exact model, or at least HP/HPE Generation of your server first please

Comment: P/N: C8R09A. Are you saying the ones it comes with are FC and cannot do a Direct Attach for iSCSI?

Comment: Ah, now that isn't DAS at all, it's is in fact the FC version - so you do need the FC HBA - ok what FC HBA do you have, they're generally made by QLogic or Emulex (now Broadcom)

Comment: How do I check that? On the SAN or on Proliant Server?   On the Proliant Server I see QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter (Storage Controller)

Comment: Ah - that makes sense - well you need to install the full HPE driver/software pack for that QLogic card

Comment: Thank you for your patience and assistance in this. Does this mean I can't configure DAS on this situation before I buy the right SAS HBA?

Comment: You don't need the SAS HBA at all, you have an FC-based MSA and an FC HBA - so just link one port from each of the ports of the HBA to one port of each of the two FC controllers in the MSA with OM3 or OM4 LC-LC fibre cables, install the HPE drivers and associated software for the QLogic FC HBA, reboot, go into the HBA software and you should hopefully see the MSA show up - then you have to log into the MSA and create a virtual disk of whatever kind you like and present it to your server's HBA ports.